# Less import path -- where does it find libraries?

Tags: less, atom-editor

I'm looking at [this code from Atom](https://github.com/atom/atom/blob/master/static/atom-ui/styles/variables/variables.less):

```
@import "ui-variables";
```

Which is being resolved to this [ui-variables.less](https://github.com/atom/atom/blob/master/static/variables/ui-variables.less) file.

My question is: by which rule did it do so?  Where's the config that tells it to look in this static/variables directory for this file?

Comment: The paths are set in [one](https://github.com/atom/atom/blob/master/script/lib/prebuild-less-cache.js) of the build scripts.

Comment: Thanks, if you make it an answer I'll accept it.